# One-line converting Enum to Int array in C#

Tags: c#, linq, enums

In trying to convert an enumeration into an int[] of its values, I initially came up with the long-winded:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Isolations.Enumerations.TypeSelectionScope))
.Cast<Isolations.Enumerations.TypeSelectionScope>().Select(t => (int)t).ToArray()
```

It works, but.. well, it ain't pretty.

I did some searching, and found people using `ConvertAll()` for this purpose, over multiple lines. So I tried it inline.

```
Array.ConvertAll(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Isolations.Enumerations.TypeSelectionScope)), value => (int)value)
```

This generates a type error, and adding some casting within is going to make it as messy as the first attempt.

I also tried a direct cast to an `int[]` to no avail:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Isolations.Enumerations.TypeSelectionScope)).Cast<int[]>()
```

Adding a `ToArray()` onto this fails also.

So, what's a single-line solution to this that isn't messy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) iterates through a collection and casts each item to `T`

You're trying to cast each instance to `int[]` - you want to cast them to `int` instead:

```
.Cast<int>()
```